# pandas data frame - reduce with initial value

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, reduce

I'm moving some of my `R` stuff to `Python`, hence I have to use `pandas.DataFrame`s. There are several things I'd like to optimise.

Suppose we've got a table

```
key value
abc 1
abc 2
abd 1
```

and we want to get a dictionary of form `{key -> list[values]}`. Here is how I get this done right now.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from StringIO import StringIO


def get_dict(df):
    """
    :param df:
    :type df: DataFrame
    """
    def f(accum, row):
        """
        :param accum:
        :type accum: dict
        """
        key, value = row[1]
        return accum.setdefault(key, []).append(value) or accum
    return reduce(f, df.iterrows(), {})


table = StringIO("key\tvalue\nabc\t1\nabc\t2\nabd\t1")
parsed_table = [row.rstrip().split("\t") for row in table]
df = DataFrame(parsed_table[1:], columns=parsed_table[0])
result = get_dict(df)  # -> {'abc': ['1', '2'], 'abd': ['1']}
```

Two things I don't like about it:

1. The fact that built-in `reduce` uses standard Python iteration protocol that kills the speed of NumPy-based data structures like `DataFrame`. I know that `DataFrame.apply` has a `reduce` mode, but it doesn't take a starting value like `dict`.
2. *(a minor drawback)* The fact that I have to use indexing to get specific values from rows. I wish I could access specific fields in a row by name like in `R`, i.e. `row$key` instead of `row[1][0]`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use groupby and apply to end with a pandas Series:

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   key  value
0  abc      1
1  abc      2
2  abd      1

In [3]: df.groupby("key").value.apply(list)
Out[3]:
key
abc    [1, 2]
abd       [1]
Name: value, dtype: object

In [4]: _3.ix['abc']
Out[4]: [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `get_dict` you could use a dict comprehension:

```
In [100]: {key:grp['value'].tolist() for key, grp in df.groupby('key')}
Out[100]: {'abc': ['1', '2'], 'abd': ['1']}
```

---

Producing a dict with lists as values automatically means you are leaving the realm of fast NumPy arrays and forcing Python to generate objects which would require Python loops to iterated over the data. When the data set is large, those Python loops can be much slower than equivalent NumPy/Pandas function calls. So your end goal may not be ideal if you are concerned about speed.

If you want to take advantage of NumPy/Pandas to perform fast(er) calculations you must keep the data in a NumPy array or Pandas NDFrame.

Comment: I'm not that much focused on speed as I'm trying not to lose it where it can be gained. Could you recommend any NumPy data structure to replace the dictionary? I've been using `lists` for this sort of stuff in `R`, but that's a different story. I chose the `dict` -> `list` combo for fast key-search and fast append that doesn't require reallocation of the entire array. I'm not aware of any hash-based NumPy structures and/or dynamic arrays. Or should I ask this in a separate question?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do next, or what your *final* goal is.
You probably should skip forming this dict, keep the DataFrame, and figure out what Pandas-based methods take you directly to the final goal.
For example, if you are planning on aggregating the values in the list then
then [`df.groupy('key').agg(...)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I just read your edited comment. Perhaps you should ask this in a separate question with all the details spelled out.

Comment: Though I absolutely adore that concise line you wrote, I've accepted Randy's answer, because it is more relevant to the title. I wish I could upvote you twice. Thank you a lot.